# How do I choose which Stack Exchange sites can advertise their questions?

Tags: support

The advertising space on any Stack Exchange site sometimes advertises a popular question from another Stack Exchange site.

Most of the time the question interests me, so I don't mind it being there. But I have no interest in the content of some of the other Stack Exchange sites. How do I filter out the questions from these sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to make you interested into more sites. There is no way to filter it out yet.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it exists. I just want to know if Stack Exchange will let me control its content.

Comment: @isme: I doubt, in this case.